# How to convert on the fly ASF video file to H.264-encoded video in MP4 or any other format supported by Windows Phone

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone, video-streaming, video-processing

Video from my IP camera is recorded and saved as an `asf` file on my computer(PC). Those files get extremely big very fast(like 1MB per 1 second), I need to convert them on the fly(while they are still build up) to smaller files(MP4) which can be streamed over the internet to the Windows phone. Those files are video only-> no audio.

Step taken:

1. While connected to the camera I record the signal from Axis camera just by: `Camera.RecordMedia("C:\\Axis\\test.asf", 8, "0")`

**Note:** When I do that the video is streamed to the `"C:\\Axis\\test.asf"` file. If I open this file by `Windows Media Classic` **while the video is recording**  I can watch it almost in real-time - it stops every few seconds and then goes -> so it seems buffer is flushed every few seconds.

I would like to open `"C:\Axis\test.asf" file during recording and convert it(until recording ends -> buffer is not flushed there) to the mp4.

Is there any chance it can be done?

All Supported video formats: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff462087(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you. My suggestion is to use [IIS Media Services](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/smooth-streaming), but it's adaptive streaming of media to Silverlight, so in order to use it WP application you will need [SMFplayer](http://smf.codeplex.com/).